# Deleting firebase data that is displayed as a Table using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase

I have an HTML file which displays a data set in firebase as a table. As the data is in firebase I am using (key,client) in clientInfo to get the key as well. This key is used for the purpose of deleting a row.

```
<table class="meeting">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, client) in clientInfo">
        <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.discount }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.vms }}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-delete tooltip" ng-click="deleteClient(key)">
            <span>Delete this client</span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But while clicking the button, the deleteClient(key) function is not called. Is it because the information of key isnt available on a Cell(td) level and is available only on a Row(tr) level in the HTML?

I am using an older version of Firebase where $as.Object() is required to store data as an Object.

My controller in Angular

```
myApp.controller('DataController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $firebase, FIREBASE_URL) { 
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/clientInfo');
var clientInfo = $firebase(ref);
$scope.clientInfo = clientInfo.$asObject();
$scope.deleteClient = function(key) {
    clientInfo.$remove(key);
};
```

Is it possible to do this in Table format? If so, what am I doing wrong? Please help me solve this issue

Comment: Note that you're on a beta release and should upgrade to the latest stable asap. Additionally, FirebaseArray is intended for handling collections and should be used here, not FirebaseObject. Also, your assumption is incorrect: deleteClient() would be invoked with `undefined` if `key` were not available. If you have verified it is not invoked, as you indicate, then this is not related to the value of `key` and nothing you've provided here will help with that. Errors in the JavaScript console? Other related code? Is that HTML fragment even in the scope of DataController?

Comment: yes, it is within the scope of the DataController. I have used .config to specify html parts and corresponding controllers to be used. I have realized the issue. I had another table named Benefits and was defining its Delete function with the same name as deleteClient. Stupid mistake on my side! Now the deleteClient(key) works well. I will modify to the latest stable asap and shift to FirebaseArray to handle collections. Thanks for letting me know about that.