# Firebase: Delete a node

Tags: firebase, angularfire, rest-firebase

Need to delete entry **trainName**

[image: Firebase DB]

I tried the below code which didnt work for me.

```
var usersRef = new Firebase('https://hosurcabapp.firebaseio.com').child('user');delee
var clientInfo = $firebase(usersRef);
$scope.clientInfo = clientInfo.$asObject();
$scope.deleteClient = function(key) {
    clientInfo.$remove(key);
};
```

Kindly help since am new to Firebase

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787182/deleting-firebase-data-that-is-displayed-as-a-table-using-angularjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not set a `null` value in Firebase, since Firebase treats `null` as an instruction to delete the node. To quote the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html):

> Passing `null` to `set()` will remove the data at the specified location.

Since your application most likely uses the `null` to signal some specific condition, you should substitute another value to signal that condition:

```
ref.child('trainName').set('<unnamed>');
```

### Update

If you *want* to delete a node, you can do:

```
usersRef.child(key).remove();
```

See also the [documentation for the Firebase delete function](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/remove.html).

Comment: I am unable to loop through all records....  The above code doesnt work.... Whats  the best solution for the same...

Comment: Is your question: "how do I delete a node using AngularFire?" That was not obvious to me from your question.

Comment: I just got to know from you that it cant be set to null... So wanna delete the record....